# i want to convert Lead into Account,Contact and Opportunity by clicking on custom button but iam getting error

Tags: apex, community

Can you please check weather this statement is correct or not, I am getting error

```
String query = 'SELECT id'+str+' FROM Lead)';
List<Lead> leadList = database.query(query);
```

```
class ConvertLead 
{
   static void Conversion()
    {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult a_desc = Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe(); 
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> a_fields = a_desc.fields.getMap();
        List<String> str = new List<String>();
        for(Schema.sObjectField fld:a_fields.values()){
            str.add(','+fld);
            //system.debug(fld);
        }
        String query = 'SELECT id'+str+' FROM Lead)';
        List<Lead> leadList = database.query(query);

        for(Lead sObjLead : leadList){
            //New Account is Created
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.name = sObjLead.name;
            acc.Industry = sObjLead.Industry;
            acc.AnnualRevenue = sObjLead.AnnualRevenue;
            acc.Rating = sObjLead.Rating;
            acc.Phone = sObjLead.Phone;
            acc.Fax = sObjLead.Fax;
            acc.Website = sObjLead.Website;
            acc.NumberOfEmployees = sObjLead.NumberOfEmployees;

            //New Opportunity is Created
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.name = sObjLead.name;
            opp.Account.Name = acc.Name;
            opp.LeadSource = sObjLead.LeadSource;

            //New Contact is Created
            Contact con = new Contact();
            con.Lastname = sObjLead.name;
            con.Account.Name = acc.Name;
            con.Title = sObjLead.Title;
            con.LeadSource = sObjLead.LeadSource;
            con.Phone = sObjLead.Phone;
            con.MobilePhone = sObjLead.MobilePhone;
            con.Fax = sObjLead.Fax;
            con.Email = sObjLead.Email;
            insert acc;
            insert opp;
            insert con;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the error message verbatim and its location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class LeadConversion
{
    Public Lead leadObj;
    Public Id leadId;
    public LeadConversion(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        leadId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        leadObj = (leadId == Null) ? new Lead():[SELECT Name FROM lead WHERE Id =: leadId];
    }
    public PageReference autoConvert()
    {
        Database.LeadConvert convertLead = new database.LeadConvert();
        convertLead.setLeadId(leadId);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
        convertLead.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult convertLeadResult = Database.convertLead(convertLead);
        Id accountId = convertLeadResult.getAccountId();
        PageReference Page = new PageReference('https://playful-raccoon-a2tqu9-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/'+accountId);
        Page.setRedirect(true);
        return Page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The trailing `)` should not be in your query.

```
    String query = 'SELECT id'+str+' FROM Lead';
```

Note that you also have other problems, such as trying to query all Lead records in the database, and having DML operations in a loop. You'll need a way to specify a Lead Id to convert just one record, and you need to use [Database.convertLead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_convertlead.htm) to correctly convert leads.

Comment: I tried ```Database.convertLead``` and this is working fine and Button is converting Lead.

 Thanks to You